# How to get the background-color value of an <a> tag with one line of code?

Tags: php, html, css, substring

I have variables `$e` and `$x`:

```
$e="<a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#4bbedd;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Aquatic Blue">" 

$x="<a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#F27EB2;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Azalea">"
```

I need the string `#4bbedd`, not searching by `"#4bbedd"` in `$e` and `#F27EB2` in `$x`.

Step by step: First I need to get string before the `;vertical` word and that string is `"<a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#4bbedd"`

Then I need to get string after the `color:` word and I got my value only  using **PHP** function and only in one line of code to get from both variables

I need to change only the variable name that contain string like `$e` then `$x`, the line logic should be like this:

```
$var = $e.functionForFindStringBeforThisWord(";vertical").functionForFindStringAfterThisWord("color:")
```

or is there another way that has only one line code?

Comment: I tried to punctuate for you. Your question was unreadable. Still is hard to understand. Please rewrite with better formatting and punctuation.

Comment: does this issue is related to php ?

Comment: Do you just search the background color? You could use a regex then. If you really need the word before vertucal you may use a regex as well or split the string at : and ;

Comment: how can i use regex to find color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting this?

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/766271)

```
<?php
$e='<a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#4bbedd;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Aquatic Blue">';
echo $var=  explode(":",explode(";",$e)[0])[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable, direct approach would be to use `preg_match()` with a pattern that specifically targets the value that follows `background-color:`.

By doing this, you will still acquire the desired substring even if the css properties are in a different order.  Sahil's method makes the assumption that you want to value of the first css property -- this will produce incorrect results if `background-color` is not present or is not the first css property.

This is a simple pattern: `/background-color:\K[^;]+/`  This says look for the substring `background-color:` then `\K` says "start matching from this point".  `[^;]+` mean match one or more characters that are not a semicolon -- this makes the match end just before the semicolon.

([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4TpmiY/1))

For improved reliability, you can include a check that `background-color:` exists in the style attribute with this:

`/style="[^"]*background-color:\K[^;]+/`

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e24af7727e349c604ee82c1387653e4a93381a1))

```
$strings=['<a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#4bbedd;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Aquatic Blue">',
'<a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="vertical-align:middle;background-color:#F27EB2;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Azalea">'
];

foreach($strings as $string){
    echo (preg_match('/style="[^"]*background-color:\K[^;]+/',$string,$out)?$out[0]:'failed'),"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
#4bbedd
#F27EB2
```

Now, even this is potentially vulnerable to false-positive matching (but honestly you'd have to be working deliberately to make it fail).

It is the default recommendation of StackOverflow that whenever you are trying to parse/extract values from an html string, you should use a DOM parser.  If you are terribly worried about false-positive matching and not worried about processing speed, you can go that route.

If you'd like to see another non-regex method, this will work more reliably than Sahil's non-regex method:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/abe94a1f3afbab22f60361bc88f99de3d4fca7b8))

```
$strings=['<a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#4bbedd;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Aquatic Blue">',
'<a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="vertical-align:middle;background-color:#F27EB2;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Azalea">'
];

foreach($strings as $string){
     // trim away all text before "background-color:", then extract the value knowing its exact position
    echo substr(strstr($string,'background-color:'),17,7),"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
#4bbedd
#F27EB2
```